# Why does my program not count every duplicate number in a certain list, but works for all others

Tags: java

I'm trying to count the number of duplicate integers in an ArrayList created from a file of roughly 20_000 values, each separated by a newline character. My current code works for every list except for a specific list that I cannot change easily and am stuck with.

```
//Arrays Class, use numerical sorting method
    //Read in each number and look for duplicates, return the number of duplicates.
    System.out.println("Creating List.....");
    File numbers = new File("src/testlist");
    List<Integer> numberlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(numbers);
        while(input.hasNextInt()){
            //int number = input.nextInt();
            numberlist.add(input.nextInt());
            //System.out.println(number);

        }
        System.out.println("List Created");
        input.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(NoSuchElementException r){
        r.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("oops");
    }
    System.out.println("Sorting Numerically.....");
    Collections.sort(numberlist);
    System.out.println(numberlist);
    System.out.println("Counting Duplicate Numbers.....");
    int duplicates = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberlist.size()-1; i++){
        if(numberlist.get(i) == numberlist.get(i+1)){
            duplicates++;
            numberlist.remove(i);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Duplicates: " + duplicates);
```

The file im using is [here](http://pastebin.com/AQH5wUaG).
I've tried other handmade test data to prove that this program works as intended, but this specific list is giving me a problem.

Comment: What is the output for the current list you are stuck with?

Comment: Why are you doing this step:  ``numberlist.remove(i);``

Comment: When you remove the current element (`remove(i)`), the following element will now be at that position, but when you then continue the loop, `i` is incremented and you didn't evaluate the element that was shifted into position. You need to decrement `i` when you `remove()`, so the loop's `i++` will leave `i` unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
numberList.remove(i)
```

the for cycle skips one element. Indeed, you remove element number `i`, and the next evaluation should continue from number `i`, and not `i+1`.

Indexes get weird things if you change the list elements while iterating, and it's never a good practice to do such things.

The cleanest way to perform this is to keep the source list without removing anything, and copying the elements into a new list, skipping duplicates.

In this way you'll have a new list, with the result (the list without duplicates) and their number is easily calculated from this list's size.

Answer (score 0):

Ass i mentioned in the comment, remove

```
numberList.remove(i)
```

and your loop will work as aspected

Easiest way to count duplicates as you need, is Casting the list to an Set and comparing the size of both. In a Set all values are unique.

```
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(numberList);

System.out.println( numberList.size() - set.size() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void countDuplicates() {
    Integer count = 0;
    List<Integer> list = getNumbersFromFile();
    Set<Integer> unique = new HashSet<Integer>(list);
    for (Integer key : unique) {
        if (Collections.frequency(list, key) > 1) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Count Of Duplicates  " + count);
}

public static List<Integer> getNumbersFromFile() {
    File numbers = new File("src/numbers.txt");
    List<Integer> numberlist = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    try {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(numbers);
        while (input.hasNextInt()) {
            // int number = input.nextInt();
            numberlist.add(input.nextInt());
            // System.out.println(number);

        }
        System.out.println("List Created");
        input.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException r) {
        r.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("oops");
    }
    return numberlist;
}
```